# Why can't I type in my react-native SearchBar?

Tags: javascript, react-native, searchbar

When I type, nothing shows up in the search bar, but it knows that I'm typing (from the print statements in my updateSearch function). From my understanding of the react-native searchBar, there isn't even anything I need to do for text to be showing up there, so I really have no idea how I could have screwed this up. This is a part of a larger project.. but I'm praying this issue doesn't have anything to do with the rest of it.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  View,
  Text,
  FlatList,
  ActivityIndicator,
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet
} from "react-native";
import Header from "../components/Header";
import { SearchBar, List, ListItem } from 'react-native-elements';

export default class Search extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      query: "",
      data: []
    };

  }

  renderHeader = () => {
    return (
    <SearchBar
    placeholder="Type Here..."
    onChangeText={this.updateSearch}
    value={this.state.query}
    lightTheme={true}
    />
    );
  }

  updateSearch = text => {
    console.log("text", text);
    const formattedSearch = text.toLowerCase();
    this.setState({ query: formattedSearch });
    console.log("text", this.state.query);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <Header text={"Search"} />
        <FlatList
          ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
        />
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: Expo.Constants.statusBarHeight
  }
});
```

Comment: The fat arrow function syntax should auto bind this to the parent context

Comment: in updateSearch, console.log("text", text); and console.log("text", this.state.query); are both printing the same thing, but it's not "adding up" its just the single key i press each time

Comment: sorry, i misunderstood your comment. i used ```console.log(this)``` and ```console.log(this.state)``` and it appears to be in the context of the search class. but from my understanding, i should be able to type in the searchbar even if i hadn't set up anything. also, one weird thing in the printout was ```"updateSearch": [Function anonymous]``` and im not sure what that means

Answer (score 3):

If you want to update your UI with render, you have to update your state.
In your FlatList component, you don't update state. So it never renders again.
You have to use state in your FlatList.

```
render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <Header text={"Search"} />
        <FlatList
          ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
          AnyProp={this.state.anyState}
        />
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thank you! AnyProp did't seem to work, but ```extraData={this.state}``` did.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the `ListHeaderComponent`.

I did a demo project to see what was happening :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { SafeAreaView, FlatList, TextInput } from 'react-native'

export default class Test extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state={value:""}
    }

    renderHeader = () =>{
        console.log("rendering") 
        return (<TextInput style={{backgroundColor:"green"}}value={this.state.value} placeholder={"Placeholder"}onChangeText={(text)=> this.setState({value : text})}></TextInput>)
    }
    render() {
        console.log(this.state.value) //Logs the value
        return (
            <SafeAreaView style={{flex:1}}>
                <FlatList
                ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
                />
            </SafeAreaView>
        )
    }

}
```

It looks like once the component has rendered, it does not update anymore. The log inside the render does actually update, but the  component do not re-render himself (probably cause the `FlatList` do not update the `ListHeaderComponent` once it is done with the first render)

I would suggest to move the SearchBar above the FlatList and enclose everything inside a `ScrollView`.

EDIT,

To confirm that it was actually updating, i created another `TextInput` and put it outside the FlatList, and it worked normally:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { SafeAreaView, FlatList, TextInput } from 'react-native'

export default class Test extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state={value:""}
    }

    renderHeader = () =>{
        console.log("rendering") 
        return (<TextInput style={{backgroundColor:"green"}}value={this.state.value} placeholder={"Placeholder"}onChangeText={(text)=> this.setState({value : text})}></TextInput>)
    }
    render() {
        console.log(this.state.value) //Logs the value
        return (
            <SafeAreaView style={{flex:1}}>
                <TextInput style={{backgroundColor:"red"}}value={this.state.value} placeholder={"Placeholder"}onChangeText={(text)=> this.setState({value : text})}></TextInput>
                <FlatList
                ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
                />
            </SafeAreaView>
        )
    }

}
```

Comment: I didn't know the header didn't get re-rendered, thank you!